# battery monitor circuit modification

Tags: integrated-circuit

A 12V battery monitor circuit is available on this page.

What can be done to modify that circuit to alarm when voltage goes below 15V ?

http://www.eleccircuit.com/low-voltage-battery-monitor-by-lm339/

Answer (score 1):

VR1 adjusts the level at which the comparator trips.  So the answer is *set VR1 appropriately*.